# Cannot export Yolov5 model using export

Tags: python, android, pytorch, yolov5

I've trained Yolov5s model in colab.research env. After training I've moved best.pt to main yolov5 directory and renamed file to yolov5s.pt.

After calling export.py i got error listed below

```
!python models/export.py
```

```
Namespace(batch_size=1, img_size=[640, 640], weights='./yolov5s.pt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models/export.py", line 33, in <module>
    model = attempt_load(opt.weights, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))  # load FP32 model
  File "./models/experimental.py", line 137, in attempt_load
    model.append(torch.load(w, map_location=map_location)['model'].float().fuse().eval())  # load FP32 model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 587, in load
    with _open_zipfile_reader(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 242, in __init__
    super(_open_zipfile_reader, self).__init__(torch._C.PyTorchFileReader(name_or_buffer))
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:145] . PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory
```

I'm trying to export this model to use it in Android App. If I use best.pt I've got other error on loading network:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.pytorch.demo.objectdetection, PID: 6935
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.pytorch.demo.objectdetection/org.pytorch.demo.objectdetection.MainActivity}: com.facebook.jni.CppException: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:222] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl
    (no backtrace available)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:222] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl
    (no backtrace available)
        at org.pytorch.NativePeer.initHybridAndroidAsset(Native Method)
        at org.pytorch.NativePeer.<init>(NativePeer.java:27)
        at org.pytorch.PyTorchAndroid.loadModuleFromAsset(PyTorchAndroid.java:31)
        at org.pytorch.demo.objectdetection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:165)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
            ... 11 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6935 SIG: 9
```

I haven't found any solutions on my own. Do you have any idea how can I fix this error?

Edit:
Fixed - I could export model if I linked to directory:

```
!python models/export.py --weights ./runs/train/exp7/weights/best.pt --img 640 --batch 1
```

Comment: May I know, are you creating the model and then put it implment the yolov5 to Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I'm using exported model in Android Studio, like i said in question and comment, I've already fixed it - linking to weight in ./runs/train/exp<your_number>/weights/best.pt<or last.py> works

Comment: Can I contact you through email, I'm still learning how to implement it

Comment: I don't think that I can help you. I've just used [this app](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/ObjectDetection), and added model trained in PyTorch (after exporting). I'm not Android Developer, I just wanted to test my model on real android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with linking model in runs directory:

```
!python models/export.py --weights ./runs/train//exp/weights/best.pt --img 640 --batch 1
```